# Cómo agregar elementos a un array con la librería numpy?

Tags: python, array, numpy

Estoy agregando datos a este array pero no se utiliza Numpy, como lo puedo hacer usando la librería?

```
import numpy as np
arreglo = []
for i in range(0,5):
    arreglo.append(input("Ingrese un valor: "))
print(arreglo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy disponen de un método `append` (`numpy.append`) pero por norma general debes evitarlo dado que cada vez que es llamado se crea una nueva copia del array. Solo sería útil en aquellos casos en los que no conozcamos de antemano el número de items final del array y no hay otra alternativa.

Lo normal es declarar un array reservando memoria para los items que vas a necesitar almacenar y luego ir indizando para asignar los valores, puedes usar:

- `numpy.zeros`/`numpy.ones`/`numpy.full` para declarar e incializar el array con ceros, unos o un valor que especifiquemos respectivamente.
- `numpy.empty` para solo declarar el array y reservar memoria para él. No se incializa, por lo que contendrá basura. Debemos asegurarnos de asignar a todos los indices un valor adecuado por tanto.

Podrías por tanto hacer algo como:

```
import numpy as np


arreglo = np.empty(5, dtype=float)

for i in range(5):
    arreglo[i] = input("Ingrese un valor: ")

print(arreglo)
```

Pero dado que es una entrada de usuario, no vendría mal validarla para evitar que el ingreso de valores no convertibles al tipo de destino (`float` en este ejemplo) causen una excepción y el fin de la ejecución.

```
import numpy as np


arreglo = np.empty(5, dtype="float")

i = 0
while i < 5:
    try:
        arreglo[i] = input("Ingrese un valor: ")
    except ValueError:
        print("No ha ingresado un número válido. Inténtelo de nuevo.")
    else:
        i += 1

print(arreglo)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!!